# Replace to first matching character using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

Trying to update some latex code. The four lines:

```
something $^\text{TT}$ and more stuff
something $^\text{T}$ and more stuff
something $^\text{M\times N}$ and more stuff
something $^\text{T} {otherstuff}$
```

should turn into

```
something $^{\text{TT}}$ and more stuff
something $^{\text{T}}$ and more stuff
something $^{\text{M\times N}}$ and more stuff
something $^{\text{T}} {otherstuff}$
```

In other words, encase the super-script by an extra `{...}`.

My attempt at using `sed` is the following

```
sed 's/\^\\text{\(.*\)}/\^{\\{text{\1}}/' testregex
```

This works on the first three lines, but the final line doesn't work and produces

```
something $^{\text{T} {otherstuff}}$
```

instead. The problem is that `sed` is matching with the last `}` on each line, but I need it to match the first `}` after the `\text{`

Also, it would be great if this could work multiple times on the same line, for example,

```
^\text{1} la la la ^\text{2}
```

should turn into

```
^{\text{1}} la la la ^{\text{2}}
```

I'm sure there's just one tiny little modification to make it work, but I can't figure it out and it's driving me nuts. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Describe what exactly you want to wrap in {...}. I understand that `^\text{SOMETHING}` needs to be converted to `^{\text{SOMETHING}}`. Is that correct? Can SOMETHING contain curly braces, i.e. nested braces? If not, it should be feasible. The regular expression to be converted would be something like `\^\\text{[^}]*}` (which would include an empty SOMETHING), i.e. replace the `.*` in your expression with a more limited `[^}]*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method to overcome the greedy regular expression problem is to explicitly look for a string of non-delimiter characters, followed by the delimiter character. At the same time, you can probably simplify your replacement syntax via:

```
sed 's/\^\(\\text{[^}]*}\)/\^{\1}/' input.tex
```

It should be possible to use

```
sed 's/\^\(\\text{[^}]*}\)/\^{\1}/g' input.tex
```

for multiple matches per line.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @SteveH you're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there! Instead of looking for "0 or more characters" inside the `\text{}` block as you do with `\\text{\(.*\)}`, look for "0 or more non-`}` characters":

```
$ sed 's/\^\\text{\([^}]*\)}/\^{\\{text{\1}}/g' foo.tex 
something $^{\{text{TT}}$ and more stuff
something $^{\{text{T}}$ and more stuff
something $^{\{text{M\times N}}$ and more stuff
something $^{\{text{T}} {otherstuff}$
```

The `g` I added to the end turns on global matching which means that all matches on the line will be replaced. Note that this assumes that matches are non-overlapping, it won't work for something like this:

```
something $^{\{text{$^{\{text{BB}}$}}$ and more stuff
```

I am assuming that isn't a problem here though.

Comment: Ah, you were faster again! :)

Comment: @AdminBee yes, but you were cleverer. Simplifying the replacement is a nice touch!

Comment: Yes, that was the key step I was missing (looking for non-} characters instead). Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

I propose this:

```bsh
$ sed 's/\$\^\\\([^}]*\)/$^\{\\\1}/' file
something $^{\text{TT}}$ and more stuff
something $^{\text{T}}$ and more stuff
something $^{\text{M\times N}}$ and more stuff
something $^{\text{T}} {otherstuff}$
```

Comment: @AdminBee Quasímodo My first attempt was the now edited one, I was trying to simplify the pattern too much it seems, thank you both. I hope there're no problems with this my original one.